# How can i avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this case?

Tags: java

Is it possible to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this case ??

```
package com;

public class Hi {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] myFirstStringArray = new String[] { "String 1", "String 2",
                "String 3" };

        if (myFirstStringArray[3] != null) {
            System.out.println("Present");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Present");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: it is always possible to avoid an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, checking against `array.length` before accessing the array element

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your array will *always* have length 3, so index 3 is *always* invalid. It's not clear what you're asking really, but while you keep using an array of length three and asking for index 3, the answer is no: you can't avoid an exception.

Comment: Are you from non-java background developer? its better to use exception handling...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the real problem, but what prevents you to check if the index is inside the array before accessing it in this case?

```
if (myIndex < myFirstStringArray.length) {
    System.out.println("Present");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Present");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In arrays, they are measured differently than numbers. The first object inside an array is considered 0. So, in your if statement, instead of a 3, you just put a 2.

```
if (myFirstStringArray[3] != null) {
        System.out.println("Present");
```

to

```
 if (myFirstStringArray[2] != null) {
        System.out.println("Present");
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `String` array contains 3 elements and you are accessing array[3] i.e. 4th element as index in 0 based and so you get this error (Exception, anyway).

To avoid the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` use an index within specified index range. And always check whether your index is `>=` `array.length`.